# Escape comma in CSV files while loading into snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have data as below and I reading data from s3 into snowflake

```
Advertising,Apps,Commerce and Shopping,Data
```

and since, is there data is coming into different columns. How to make sure data doesn't spill into different columns?

Comment: set `FIELD_DELIMITER` to something you know is not in the data, it's default is `,`  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv

Comment: This is one reason why "Text Qualifier" modes exists for export and inport - in this case you would have to set the export to "text qualify" the csv output - or choose a different delimiter.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim: If I change FIELD_DELIMITER to other I am getting null values for all columns, It should be ',' but it is unable to distinguish